# Store subprocess.call stdout in a variable and load it back as json

Tags: python, json

I want to run a subprocess command, store stdout in a variable and later load into json

```
variable=""
subprocess.call('command',stdout=variable,shell=True)
instance_details=json.loads(variable)

Error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `stdout=variable` you can try:

```
variable = subprocess.Popen("<command>",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
print variable.stdout.read()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'stdout'

Comment: @user60679, my bad it should be `Popen` not `call`. Checkout the corrected answer